# How to get the only hours and minutes in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-blade

I am trying to get hours and minutes and seconds in blade, normally I use like below

```
{{$calllog['delivery_date']}}
```

but now my requirement is to get hours and minutes and seconds.
here is how I tried to get

```
$calllog['delivery_date']->todatestring()}}
```

Yeah, I think I misuse for this function, can someone help me out? I am new in Laravel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->format('H:i:s') }}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your variable is a DateTime, you can use this :

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($calllog['delivery_date'])->format('H:i:s') }}
```

Or simplest way (depends on your version) :

```
{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->format('H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($calllog['delivery_date'])->format('H:i:s') }} this one work for me, the below is showing me like "Call to a member function format() on string"

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get minutes and hours as separate values:

```
{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->minute }}
{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->hour }}
```

You you're looking for solution to show hours and minutes as a string, use `format()`.

For example, this will return 02:12:

```
{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->format('h:i') }}
```

And this will return 14:12:

```
{{ $calllog['delivery_date']->format('H:i') }}
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: i tried above you mentioned its showing like "Call to a member function format() on string" then i tried like this {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($calllog['delivery_date'])->format('H:i:s') }} ,its worked , anyway sir thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @ThanHtutOo since you've shown `$calllog['delivery_date']->todatestring()}}` I've assumed that it's a Carbon instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in blade:

```
date("h:i a")
```