# Show only hours minutes and seconds - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to print only hours minutes and seconds

[image]

```
{{$tracking->created_at}}
```

with this variable I pass the `created_at` row.

how do i remove the date and just leave the time?

Comment: You could use `substr(created_at, 11)` in your `select`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 1):

You can use the date function for it.

```
{{ date('h:i:s'),strtotime($tracking->created_at) }}

h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
i   Minutes with leading zeros                      00 to 59
s   Seconds, with leading zeros                     00 through 59
```

If you want to use carbon then

```
Carbon::parse($item['created_at'])->format('h:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// print 23:11:11
{{ date('H:i:s', strtotime("2011-11-11 23:11:11")) }}

// print 11:11:11 PM
{{ date('h:i:s A', strtotime("2011-11-11 23:11:11")); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way IMHO

```
{{ $row->created_at->format('H:i:s') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Carbon to modify how you render the date. Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285628/how-to-get-the-only-hours-and-minutes-in-laravel-blade) I think it'll help.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using carbon,
In Controller

```
$created = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($tracking->created_at));
```

And then, add this in the view :

```
{{ $created ->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::now())->format(%h hours and %i minutes and %s seconds'); }}
```